# NoSuchMethod when trying to execute HelloWorld in Scala on Zeppelin with local JAR as dependency

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a problem with execution of local .jar on Zeppelin. I'm adding dependency jar via [this guide](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/manual/dependencymanagement.html), but when I go to notebook and try to execute

```
println("Hi")
```

I'm getting the stack listed below:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.hd$1()Ljava/lang/Object;
at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings.loop$1(MutableSettings.scala:64)
at scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings.processArguments(MutableSettings.scala:91)
at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:706)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When there is no dependencies in interpreter, everything works fine.
I know that might be scala dependencies issues, but I've tried with different versions of scala and that won't help.
Also `util.Properties.versionString` on Zeppelin notebook returns `res1: String = version 2.11.8` - it's the same version as in my test .jar file.